# drupal entity property show in views

Tags: 7, entities

I am using **[ECK](http://drupal.org/project/eck)** module to create entity type. Now i want to show property of that entity to be show with views. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: In dev version the property is available in view. :)

Answer (score 0):

If ECK doesn't define the entity and property types for views, you will have to do that yourself using either `hook_views_data` or `hook_views_data_alter`.